# Reference: Renormalization Group and scale invariance in statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, renormalization, scale-invariance

Can anyone recommend a book/resource that succinctly explains how the Renormalization Group idea is applied in statistical mechanics?

I have some background in undergraduate-level statmech, but none in quantum field theory, and I am finding this idea difficult to get physical intuition for.

Comment: More on [renormalization](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renormalization+resource-recommendations).